# Jquery Selectors - Selecting a div that fall before the clicked div

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically generated code that looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="item_a">
             TEST
      </div>
      <div class="item_b">
             TEST 2
      </div>

</div>

<div class="trigger_div">
      Click Me
</div>




<div class="container">
      <div class="item_a">
             TEST
      </div>
      <div class="item_b">
             TEST 2
      </div>

</div>

<div class="trigger_div">
      Click Me
</div>




<div class="container">
      <div class="item_a">
             TEST
      </div>
      <div class="item_b">
             TEST 2
      </div>

</div>

<div class="trigger_div">
      Click Me
</div>
```

This is how I am trying to grab the values using jquery selectors:

```
$(".trigger_div").on('click', function () {
         var item_a = $(this).closest(".container").children(".item_a");
         var item_b = $(this).closest(".container").children(".item_b");
    });
```

I am getting undefined values for item_a and item_b. I want to be able to grab the values in the "item_a" and "item_b" fields of the div that comes right before the "trigger_div"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.prev().children

```
$(".trigger_div").on('click', function () {
    var item_a = $(this).prev().children("item_a");
    var item_b = $(this).prev().children("item_b");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.closest` finds the ancestors of your selector, you want to use `.prev()` and specify an element:

```
$(".trigger_div").on('click', function () {
     var item_a = $(this).prev(".container").children(".item_a");
     var item_b = $(this).prev(".container").children(".item_b");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.prev()`, not `.closest()` since you're looking for a sibling not an ancestor, and closest looks at ancestors.

```
$(".trigger_div").on('click', function () {
    var item_a = $(this).prev(".container").find(".item_a").html();
    var item_b = $(this).prev(".container").find(".item_b").html();
    console.log(item_a, item_b);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PbYcT/)**

Ref:

- [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)
- [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the `.` class-selector, and you used `.closest` instead of `.prev` write it like this

```
$("#clear_filter_btn").on('click', function () {
     var item_a = $(this).prev(".container").children(".item_a");
     var item_b = $(this).prev(".container").children(".item_b");
});
```

and it should work.

also, you didnt grab their "value" (innerHTML) add `.html()` like so

```
var item_a = $(this).prev(".container").children(".item_a").html();
```

**edit**

seeing as you changed `#clear_filter_btn` to `.trigger_div` you may want to change that in above code as well, but note you probably want to use a `id` in this case to make the trigger unique, using a class for this can cause big problems in large sites.